# Finding the point of intersection between a line and a cubic spline

Tags: c#, algorithm, computational-geometry

[image: Diagram]

I need a way to programmatically find the point of intersection between a line f(x), which originates from the origin, and a cubic spline defined by 4 points. The line is guaranteed to intersect the center segment of the spline, between X1 and X2.

I have tried a number of approaches but cannot seem to get the expected result. I suspect my problem lies somewhere in my handling of complex numbers.

Can anyone find the problem with my code, or else suggest a different approach?

```c
    private Vector2 CubicInterpolatedIntersection(float y0, float y1, 
                            float y2, float y3, float lineSlope, lineYOffset)
    {
        // f(x) = lineSlope * x + lineYOffset
        // g(x) = (a0 * x^3) + (a1 * x^2) + (a2 * x) + a3

        // Calculate Catmull-Rom coefficients for g(x) equation as found 
        // in reference (1). These 
        double a0, a1, a2, a3;
        a0 = -0.5 * y0 + 1.5 * y1 - 1.5 * y2 + 0.5 * y3;
        a1 = y0 - 2.5 * y1 + 2 * y2 - 0.5 * y3;
        a2 = -0.5 * y0 + 0.5 * y2;
        a3 = y1;

        // To find POI, let 'g(x) - f(x) = 0'. Simplified equation is:
        // (a0 * x^3) + (a1 * x^2) + ((a2 - lineSlope) * x) 
        //                         + (a3 - lineYOffset) = 0

        // Put in standard form 'ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0'
        double a, b, c, d;
        a = a0;
        b = a1;
        c = a2 - lineSlope;
        d = a3 - lineYOffset;


        // Solve for roots using cubic equation as found in reference (2).
        //  x = {q + [q^2 + (r-p^2)^3]^(1/2)}^(1/3) 
        //         + {q - [q^2 + (r-p^2)^3]^(1/2)}^(1/3) + p
        //  Where...
        double p, q, r;
        p = -b / (3 * a);
        q = p * p * p + (b * c - 3 * a * d) / (6 * a * a);
        r = c / (3 * a);

        //Solve the equation starting from the center.
        double x, x2;
        x = r - p * p;
        x = x * x * x + q * q;
        // Here's where I'm not sure. The cubic equation contains a square 
        // root. So if x is negative at this point, then we need to proceed
        // with complex numbers.
        if (x >= 0)
        {
            x = Math.Sqrt(x);
            x = CubicRoot(q + x) + CubicRoot(q - x) + p;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x)); 
            // x now represents the imaginary component of 
            //                       a complex number 'a + b*i'
            // We need to take the cubic root of 'q + x' and 'q - x'
            // Since x is imaginary, we have two complex numbers in 
            // standard form. Therefore, we take the cubic root of 
            // the magnitude of these complex numbers
            x = CubicRoot(Math.Sqrt(q * q + x * x)) + 
                 CubicRoot(Math.Sqrt(q * q + -x * -x)) + p;
        }

        // At this point, x should hold the x-value of 
        //      the point of intersection.
        // Now use it to solve g(x).

        x2 = x * x;
        return new Vector2((float)Math.Abs(x), 
           (float)Math.Abs(a0 * x * x2 + a1 * x2 + a2 * x + a3));
    }
```

References:

1. http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/
2. http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
if (x >= 0)
{  // One real root and two imaginaries.
    x = Math.Sqrt(x);
    x = CubicRoot(q + x) + CubicRoot(q - x) + p;
}
else
{  // Three real roots.
    x = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x)); 


    x_1 = Math.Sign(q)*2*(q*q + x*x)^(1/6)*Math.Cos(Math.Atan(x/q)/3) + p;
    x_2 = Math.Sign(q)*2*(q*q + x*x)^(1/6)*Math.Cos(Math.Atan(x/q)/3 + Math.PI*2/3) + p;
    x_3 = Math.Sign(q)*2*(q*q + x*x)^(1/6)*Math.Cos(Math.Atan(x/q)/3 + Math.PI*4/3) + p;
}
```

You can compute `( )^(1/6)` with `Math.Pow(  , 1/6)` or your `Math.Sqrt(CubicRoot( ))` or `Math.Sqrt(Cbrt( ))`. See the [following thread on Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/784cfdc1-1e47-448e-83e8-a94197f58e24/).

Be careful with `q = 0`. `( Atan(x/0) = pi/2 radians. Cos(Atan(x/0)/3) = Sqrt(3)/2 )`

Comment: hmm... that doesn't seem to be working either. I tested it using 4 points evenly spaced and at an equal distance from the origin to define g(x). Then I checked the result of the function at each pi/8 interval. The result should resemble a sine wave, but it is instead erratic, non-continuous, and always positive. Perhaps there is another problem somewhere?

Comment: Also, I can say for sure that the problem is somewhere in this function and not elsewhere in the program because when i replace it with a regular linear intersection function, the result is as expected.

Comment: Can you send me the 3th order polinomial to solve? The function solve all the polinomial that I tested.

Comment: You can test the others solutions (there are three solutions for a 3th order):

x = Math.Sign(q)*2*(q*q + x*x)^(1/6)*Math.Cos(Math.Atan(x/q)/3 + Math.PI*2/3) + p;

x = Math.Sign(q)*2*(q*q + x*x)^(1/6)*Math.Cos(Math.Atan(x/q)/3 + Math.PI*4/3) + p;

Answer (score 0):

For a quadratic equation there exists atleast 1 single real root. 
Use this method for finding the roots http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots